# Xcode Error Message With No Location Info

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

I recently started coding c++, using Xcode. I was making a pong project, and while coding, I came across this error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). It also said it was something with clang. I am new to Xcode and c++ so I am not sure what to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you show us the full error? You can remove personal paths, but try to give as much information as you can.

Comment: https://motomaid.wixsite.com/pongcode

Comment: Sorry about the wait. Been a heck of a week.